# How do I reset cached javascript variables and functions in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the idea is that 3 colored balls are displayed in the browser as a randomly selected video is played that corresponds to one of the colored balls.  the user just has to click on the correct corresponding ball.  when they do, that video gets hidden and the next one is shown also the corresponding coloured ball for this next video becomes the only selectable ball.

But, it seems like the variables, or the functions or the browser or something is remembering the previous selections and not resetting properly. I get 2 video's showing up side by side at the same time instead of one.  and once a colored ball is triggered once by the .click function, it always functions even though it shouldn't because the .click function has already been set to and working with the next random colour.
how can I stop this from happening?

Here's screen shot of what it should like  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYL8P.jpg)
.  My html and JQuery/javascript is as follows:

```js
selectColour()

function selectColour() {

  var myArray = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];

  //randomly select one of the colours in the array above.
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
  var concat = myArray[rand];

  random();

  function random() {

    //unhide/show the video of the random colour chosen.
    $('#' + (concat) + 'vid').show();

    //if the correct coloured ball is clicked, then hide the video.
    $('#' + (concat)).click(function() {
        $('#' + (concat) + 'vid').hide();
      }
    });
  selectColour()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Video links: These are all hidden until called by Jquery .show() -->

<iframe id="yellowvid" src="linkRemoved" width="240" height="320" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id="bluevid" src="linkRemoved" width="240" height="320" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id="redvid" src="linkRemoved" width="240" height="320" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<!--selectable coloured balls-->
<img id="blue" src="img/blue_dot.jpg" />
<img id="yellow" src="img/yellow_dot.jpg" />
<img id="red" src="img/red_dot.jpg" />
```

Comment: I think there are some syntax error in the javascript code you pasted. Can you check it is correct?

Comment: All your variables should get dumped as soon as the function scope closes and does not get a closure; from the first look it seems like you created an infite recursive closure for `selectColour ` as you call it in itself, so it'll just go on forever?

Comment: @Clemens thanks Clemens, you're right! I moved myArray outside of the function selectColour() and added a new variable that concat updates as its own value.  Each coloured ball now reads that new variable which means the function now closes after each iteration.  Thanks you.

Comment: No problemerinio dude.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments it looks like you created an infite recursive closure for selectColour making it being called forever